# Acces to a Database with ODBC in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, odbc

Suppose this:

Usually I access to a DB just with the classic windows ODBC (Oracle Database).

So i've the TNS, the Username and the Password.

Usually i use this string to connect Java to an oracle DB:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid","username","password");
```

But if i dont know the IP how i can connect my application to the database using ODBC??

Thanks.

Comment: Normaly @ip should be replaceable by `hostname` If DNS service is set up properly for your machine everything will automagicaly work..and this doesn't have anything to do with ODBC

Comment: To connect database you should have `hostname` or `IP address`

Comment: JDBC and ODBC are two completely separate tech stacks.

Comment: There is no ODBC connection in your question, only JDBC

Comment: Look up sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver. Note that the ODBC Bridge is gone in Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add this before using the connection string

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "TNS/FILE/PATH");
```

and specifing only the TNS in the connection string.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tnsname","username","password"
```